# How to use my existing funciton global.parseData(id, name, url) in `await page.evaluate(indexTotal => {` in Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

**QUESTION:**

What is the proper syntax to use my global.parseData function inside `page.evaluate` ?

---

**EDIT:**

Current Code:

getData.js

```
    getData: function() {

            let getData = async () => {
                url = 'url';

                await page.exposeFunction('parseData', (items2, items3, item2, ...) => global.parseData(items2, items3, item2, ...));

                const thedata = await page.evaluate( async() => {

                    var items = [];
                    var items2 = [];
                    var items3 = [];

                    $('.htmlElement').find('.childElements').each(function(ind) {
                        ...

                        var returnedObject = await window.parseData(items2, items3, item2, ...);

                        items.push(returnedObject.item);
                        items2 = returnedObject.items2;
                        items3 = returnedObject.items3;

                    });

                    var largeObject = {
                        items: items,
                        items2: items2,
                        items3: items3
                    }

                    console.log("RETURNED OBJECT: "+JSON.stringify(returnedObject));

                    return largeObject;

                }).catch( error => {
                    console.log("ERROR: "+error);
                });

                browser.close();
                return thedata;
            }

            getData().then(largeObject => {

                global.saveData(largeObject);

            });
    }
```

app.js

```
global.parseData = function(items2, items3, item2, ...) {

    ...


    if(!item2 || item2 == "") {
        ...
    }
    else {
        items2.push(item2);
        var item3 = ...;
        items3.push(item3);
    }

    var item = {
        ...
    }

    var largeObject = {
        item: item,
        items2: items2,
        items3: items3
    }

    console.log("LARGE OBJECT: "+JSON.stringify(largeObject));

    return largeObject;
}
```

**CONSOLE.LOG OUTPUT:**

```
RETURNED OBJECT: {}
LARGE OBJECT: {data}
RETURNED OBJECT: {}
RETURNED OBJECT: {}
RETURNED OBJECT: {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem

The error is coming from this part of the code:

```js
page.evaluate((global.parseData(id,name,url)) //...
```

You have to pass a function to `page.evaluate` with arguments first. You are passing a mix of arguments and function calls here.

#### Solution

To use a function from your Node.js environment inside the browser context, you need to expose it using [`page.exposeFunction`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.19.0/docs/api.md#pageexposefunctionname-puppeteerfunction).

**Code Sample**

```js
// expose the function to the page
await page.exposeFunction('parseData', (id, name, url) => {
    // do calculations
    return 'RESULT';
});

// Alternative: Call another function
await page.exposeFunction('parseData2', (id, name, url) => global.parseData(id,name,url));

// run code inside the page
await page.evaluate(async (indexTotal) => {
    // run code inside the page, set variables
    // ...
    const result = await window.parseData(id, name, url); // call your Node.js function
}, indexTotal);
```

Comment: @TheProgrammer You can call your global function from within the exposed function. Changed the answer to contain an example.

Comment: I can see that global.parseData is being executed through its console.logs and the returned value in the end does have the data in global.parseData. But result is actually assigned an empty object. I wonder what may be causing this.

Comment: @TheProgrammer Hard to say what the problem is without seeing the code. Are you trying to pass DOM nodes from `page.evaluate` maybe?

Comment: I have updated my question with additional code/context. Also, I cannot put await in front of window.parseData because of the following error: `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`

Comment: @TheProgrammer There was an `async` missing in my code. I added it.

Comment: Just tried with the additional async and I still get the await related error. Also updated the additional code in my question with the added async.

Comment: @TheProgrammer You've added a lot of code there. Please try to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead.

Comment: Adding the async to `$('.htmlElement').find('.childElements').each(async function(ind) {` did let the `await window.parseData` execute though. Still some missing data, going to debug a bit more.

Comment: I can't mark all functions inside getData as async because it will destroy the order in which the objects are returned (the final object being returned first). To think all I want to do is expose a global function to keep my code DRY.